# IntelliJ IDEA Outgoing commits

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.5 and I have a problem: for some projects IDEA shows that there are outgoing commits (green dot on the bottom right corner and green arrow) and for some projects it does not. Also, I noticed that when IDEA shows that there are outgoing commits, an "Update" button is enabled on local branch.

Not showing:
[image: Not working] 
 Showing:
 [image: Working]

What can be the reason? I tried invalidating caches, but that did not help. Also, I did not found any issues about that on the Internet. It probably has something to do with Git, but I don't understand what it really is...

I mean, I *want* it to show this green dot

Comment: You didn't say, but are you sure your local _isn't_ different from the remote? What does `git diff master origin/master` output?

Comment: When I have non-pushed commits, it shows output, and when there are no commits, then there is no output either. But in the first case there is no point, and in the second there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, if an update is greyed out, most likely your master has no tracked branch set.

You may easily fix this by checking out master and trying to update it.

An error should pop up saying
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, just needed to set tracking branch, now it works.